# $\int\sin^6(x)\cos(x)dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

$$\int\sin^6(x)\cos(x)\,dx.$$

Apparently...

$$\int\sin^6(x)\cos(x)\,dx= \int\sin^6(x)\,d\sin(x)x = \frac{1}{7}\sin^7(x)+c.$$

Can somebody explain the second equality? Shouldn't there be a $dx$ after it?

Comment: Set $\sin x=u$ and proceed

Comment: What does "apparently" refer to - that is, what is your source material for this solution? I personally don't care for the way it is written. I would apply @labbhattacharjee's hint: set $u = \sin x$. Then $du = \cos x dx$, and your integral transforms as $\int u^{6}du$, which is a lot more sensible than what's written.

Comment: Well I think my answer is one of the simplest that could be written, but I'm not sure if simplicity is what you need or not.  But I'm wondering why I've seen so many postings lately in which the "equals" sign is place outside of the math tags rather than inside.  Is there some web page you're relying on that told you to do it that way?  (I corrected it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral is a good example of substitution.
$$
\int \sin^6(x)\cos(x)\;dx
$$
Let $\color{green}{u=\sin(x)}$, then $\frac{du}{dx} = \cos(x)$, and we write this as $\color{blue}{du = \cos(x)dx}$.
So
$$
\int \color{green}{\sin(x)}^6\color{blue}{\cos(x)\;dx} = \int \color{green}{u}^6 \color{blue}{du} = \frac{1}{7}u^7 + C = \frac{1}{7}\sin^7(x) + C
$$
In your notation you have
$$
\int \sin^6(x) d\sin(x)
$$
and the $d\sin(x)$ is sometimes used to indicate the change of variable that we have used substituting $u$ for $\sin(x)$. So the $du$ is like the $d\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 6):

Directly, using

$$\int f'(x) f(x)^n\,dx=\frac{f(x)^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$

with $\;f(x)=\sin x\;$ , in your case...

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** That's what you have

$$ \int (f(x))^n f'(x)dx = \frac{(f(x))^{n+1}}{n+1}+c .$$

You can see this by using the substitution $u=\sin(x)$.

Comment: I thought the substitution was $u=\sin(x)$, not $u=\sin^6(x)$..

Comment: @ireallydonknow: yes, you are right. It is a typo.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your second equality has $\sin x$ sandwiched between $d$ and $x$ as in "dx".

Correctly stated, we have:

$$\int\sin^6(x)\cos(x)\,dx= \int\sin^6(x)\,\dfrac{d}{dx}(\sin(x))\,dx  = \frac{1}{7}\sin^7(x)+c.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \sin x = \cos x
$$
Hence
$$
d\sin x = \cos x\,dx.
$$

In other words, the infinitely small increment of $\sin x$ is equal to $\cos x$ times the infinitely small increment of $x$.